# Saying "sure" to reply to a stranger's "have a great day"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Is it considered rude to say simply "sure" in response to some stranger's "great day"?

Comment: Sure is not a nice thing to say if you don't know someone. It can be negative depending on your tone.

Comment: @Lambie, Thanks. Indeed, even I am not a native speaker in English, I could sense to a certain degree some hostility in that reply... Just want to get more information to see if it is me overthinking.

Comment: Well, to me, it can range from slightly sarcastic to downright hostile. Of course.

Comment: @Lambie, Also, I am an asian who just moved to US for a few months. I got the reply from a white female. Not sure if it is that I was treated specially.

Comment: Well, I would have to have been there to tell. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is customary to either return the kindness or offer some sort of appreciation.

"Thanks, you too," or simply "you too," is what I hear most often. It would also be acceptable to give a warm "thank you."

You will find that simply accepting the gesture—even though it's just routine politeness—sometimes throws off the other person. "Sure" or "okay" aren't typical responses.

It's not rude, per se, but it's less than ideal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I ask if "sure" conveys anything negative??

Comment: @GaryM - It can, but that depends largely on tone. If the word "sure" is uttered glumly, then people will often assume it is meant sarcastically or facetiously, and not regard it as a polite and friendly response.

Comment: It's not negative, but it's neutral in a situation where your response is expected to be positive. So it usually won't be rude, as I mentioned, but it won't be what people expect. That could lead to a negative reaction in some instances.

Comment: @MattBecher, Thanks. In fact, the situation is that I was the stranger who got the reply from someone in an elevator. I am not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: If it was from a stranger, they may have just been having a bad day. Some people don't keep up with niceties when they're feeling bad or irritated, even if it's something as meaningless as this phrase. I wouldn't think anything of it.

Comment: @MattBecher, Thank you. It is great to learn that it is not me treating people not very fair. :)